# access element attributes using SoapUI api (with java)

Tags: xml, soapui, soap-client

This is an xml example from a wsdl :

```
 <s:complexType name="Relation">
   <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RelationName" type="s:string"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="InternetAddress" type="s:string"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="E_mail" type="s:string"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Obsolete" type="s:boolean"/>
   </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

The listing above is an operation's input of a webservice.
I need to print its attribute like : 
Element

- name
- type
- minOccur
- maxOccur
- or any other attributes

Is there any way to get Element attributes from wsdl description using **soapUI api** (I am working with **4.0.1** version) and **java** ??

*we can get that using element.getAttributes() with dom or jdom api but I must do it with SoapUI api*

Comment: I remember, there is another question posted by you on the same lines and hope this is same one. If you need to read the xml using java, see [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using SoapUI api to get Input's attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545789/using-soapui-api-to-get-inputs-attribute)

Comment: I sad ** using soapUI api** not dom :)

Comment: Also I sad that I am working on wsdl files (not sample xml files). And us you know WSDL, may be very large and be spread across multiple files (there may be other import WSDL or XML schema).

It is therefore best to rely on an existing library. Besides I am using SoapUI api for other purposes. So If you are familiar with what I am talking about please amaz me with your suggestions ;)

Comment: Noobs ! noobs everywhere !!